# Laravel Migration default unique value

Tags: laravel, migration

I have a migration which creates users, now I would like to add that migration and give each new user a unique random value from my array. So far the values are random but not unique, how can I do that?

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->string('theme_color')->default($this->generateColor())
            ->after('password')
            ->unique();
    });
}

public function down()
{
    Schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->dropColumn('theme_color');
    });
}

public function generateColor()
{
    $colors = [
        '#94A3B8',
        '#64748B',
        '#F87171',
        '#EA580C',
        '#FDE68A',
        '#713F12',
        '#A3E635',
        '#4ADE80',
        '#A7F3D0',
        '#99F6E4',
        '#22D3EE',
        '#0284C7',
        '#2563EB',
        '#8B5CF6',
        '#D946EF',
        '#9D174D',
        '#F43F5E'
    ];
    $k = array_rand($colors);
    return $colors[$k];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Migration runs only once. So, you cannot set different values there, What your migration will do is it will set one random value as default forever.

To achieve this use Eloquent: Mutators & Casting (setter method) in the Laravel model, check the documentation https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-mutators#defining-a-mutator